# Isotope JS Packery Tile Gaps

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope, packery

I’m using the [Packery layout mode in Isotope JS](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html).  I was using Masonry, but I found I was getting more desirable results using this mode instead, but I’m totally open to other options.  I’m also using it integrated with the Bootstrap responsive grid as described [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/extras.html#bootstrap).  Everything is working great with the exception of one thing.

I have a single-wide tile, then a double-wide tile, followed by several single-wide tiles.  Everything looks great in the Bootstrap 4 and 3 column configurations.  As soon as I collapse it to the 2 column configuration, I only have 1 single-wide tile up top in the first position.  The double-wide is below, and all the single wide tiles show up side-by-side (2 per row) all the way down, as desired.  There is even 1 tile left over at the bottom by itself, that if rearranged, each single-wide tile would be paired with another of the same type.

Here are some quick grids of the 3 different column configurations for some visualization:

```
4-Columns:     3-Columns:  2-Columns:
+--+--+--+--+  +--+--+--+  +--+--+
|88|88888|88|  |88|88888|  |88|  <---this empty tile right here...
|88|88|88|88|  |88|88|88|  |88888|
|88|88|  |  |  |88|88|88|  |88|88|
+--+--+--+--+  |88|  |  |  |88|88|
               +--+--+--+  |88|88|
                           |88<------...should be filled up by this 
                           +--+--+      tile (or one before it)
```

Here's a repro:

```js
$('.grid').isotope({
 packery: {
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
 },
 itemSelector: '.grid-item',
 percentPosition: true,
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: red;
}
.two {
  background-color: orange;
}
.three {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.four {
  background-color: green;
}
.five {
  background-color: blue;
}
.six {
  background-color: purple;
}
.seven {
  background-color: red;
}
.eight {
  background-color: orange;
}
.nine {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="grid">
   <div class="grid-sizer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 one">
    <div class="grid-item-content">ONE</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 two">
    <div class="grid-item-content">TWO</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 three">
    <div class="grid-item-content">THREE</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 four">
    <div class="grid-item-content">FOUR</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 five">
    <div class="grid-item-content">FIVE</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 six">
    <div class="grid-item-content">SIX</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 seven">
    <div class="grid-item-content">SEVEN</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 eight">
    <div class="grid-item-content">EIGHT</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 nine">
    <div class="grid-item-content">NINE</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: You can post your isotope code, right. How is that proprietary? Anyway, there are a lot of ideas but tough without at least some basic code.

Comment: @Macsupport Code posted :)

Comment: 2 things I see. You are loading 2 versions of jQuery (old one 1.12.4 and new 3.1.1). Bad idea. You are also not loading the packery layout for isotope. This layout mode is not included in isotope.pkgd.js and must be installed separately, [Download it here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metafizzy/isotope-packery/master/packery-mode.pkgd.min.js)

Comment: The two versions of jQuery were not intended.  Leftover copy pasta from updating references to mimic the environment I'm working in.  That was corrected.  As for the Packery library being separate, it looks like that was it.  I'll post the solution for others in a few minutes.

Comment: For your future questions on Stackoverflow, usually one has the person answering the question  post it and then accepts it.

Comment: Right.  I was wondering why you answered with a comment, I have no way to issue you credit for your help.  I provided the working code since I had it written out (with your help) for others to reference, and to try and stick to format.  Go ahead and copy/repost what I did with your answer, and I'd be happy to delete my post and issue you credit, bud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution below (credit to @Macsupport !):

```js
$('.grid').packery({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: red;
}
.two {
  background-color: orange;
}
.three {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.four {
  background-color: green;
}
.five {
  background-color: blue;
}
.six {
  background-color: purple;
}
.seven {
  background-color: red;
}
.eight {
  background-color: orange;
}
.nine {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/packery@2/dist/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="grid">
   <div class="grid-sizer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 one">
    <div class="grid-item-content">ONE</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 two">
    <div class="grid-item-content">TWO</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 three">
    <div class="grid-item-content">THREE</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 four">
    <div class="grid-item-content">FOUR</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 five">
    <div class="grid-item-content">FIVE</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 six">
    <div class="grid-item-content">SIX</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 seven">
    <div class="grid-item-content">SEVEN</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 eight">
    <div class="grid-item-content">EIGHT</div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 nine">
    <div class="grid-item-content">NINE</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```